Failed to get pid info for pid 0: Operation not permitted xcode
I get this error message when trying to build any project on Xcode. In addition it doesn't not attach any project to the simulator. I have already tried the normal troubleshooting like restarting computer, erasing all content from the simulator and updating my macOS version. I suspect it has something to do with the certificates
Failed to get pid info for pid 0: Operation not permitted xcode

It's difficult to tell what's going on without a bit more information about your Xcode setup. For example, did you install Xcode from the App Store or by downloading it from the developer website? And do you have multiple versions of simulators installed? Or perhaps deleted some simulators? Perhaps there's some other useful information you could provide that I haven't considered.

Hello, so I narrowed it down to the specific iMessage extension template if you tried to run this straight out of the box it will not let you for some reason.
